# JavaScript not working on refresh - must clear cache

Tags: javascript, caching, squarespace

I've implemented [this script](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/79934/wexley-is-there-a-clickthrough-workaround.html?childToView=79951#answer-79951) on my Squarespace website using the wexley template to make images in a gallery act as links (Wexley does not support clickthrough URLs natively).

It works fine, but if I add any thumbnails to the gallery it will not work until the browser cache is cleared.

I am wondering if there is a way to fix this? Perhaps through:

1) setting an expiry on the cache? I am not in developer mode so this would have to go into a header injection

2) Versioning? I tried hosting the javascript as a file elsewhere on my site. This worked (it pulled the script from another location) but still get the same issue, even when I upload a new script file and point to that after updating the page!

Answer (score 0):

You can force the client to download the field again. To accomplish this you need to make the clients browser to think it doesnt have the script in cache. You can do this changing the file name.

Imagine you have this folder structure:

- index.html
- index.js

If in your `index.html` you reference the script like `src="index.js"` you may force clients to download just apendding a query string to the import: `src="index.js?0"`

Now clients browsers will check if this file is in cache, and since it isnt, they will fetch from the server.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. It seems that there is something I am missing.

Comment: Here is what I did (Squarespace):

1) Created a "Gallery Page" and added 1 photo with a "Clickthrough URL" to a fake page.

2) Created a new page called JS Files, and from there, uploaded the script as "linktest.js"

3) In the "PAGE HEADER CODE INJECTION" added <script src="/s/linktest2.js"></script>

4) Opened the page in safari. The thumbnail worked as expected (first visit).

5) Added another thumbnail with a fake link, and changed to <script src="/s/linktest2.js?1.0"></script> in the code injection

6) Reloaded in safari - second thumb did not work, clear cache, refresh, worked

Comment: Took another look with Safari and noticed that the script itself is not getting cached, so something else is and that is preventing the script from working correctly on the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the resource loading on my page I realized that the script was not being cached so it was something else getting cached that was interfering.

Because I am not in dev mode, I implemented a fix that relies on appending the URL with the date of the update, and then setting up 301 redirects.

The URL and redirects (2 total) would have to be updated when any content is added.

If anyone sees issues with this (relating to SEO or some unknown), I would appreciate your feedback.